# Deploy django project with more application using Apache

Tags: python-3.x, django

I'm trying to deploy a website using Apache and mod_wsgi, my project has more applications

```
Project/
├── Article
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── Client
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── ManagementSoftware
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── Order
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── Sites
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── Supplier
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── Project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.py.save
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
└── requiements.txt
```

I have set up the Apache config file like that

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAlias project.xyz

        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/Project/Project>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess Project python-home=/var/www/vhosts/Prohect/env/
        WSGIProcessGroup Project
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/Project/Project/wsgi.py process-group=Project

        Alias /static/ /var/www/vhosts/Project/ManagementSoftware/static/
        <Directory /var/www/vhosts/Project/ManagementSoftware/static>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I launch the project I get Error 500 Internal Server Error.
When the app had only one application (ManagmentSoftware) it used to work, so I am pretty sure the problem is about that change.

Thanks in advance everyone, I have already tried to search for a couple of hours but I couldn't find anything

**EDIT - Apache Log**

```
[Sun Jan 23 14:08:08.310471 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 48106:tid 140244498315008] [remote 79.53.204.195:37790] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun Jan 23 14:08:08.310502 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 48106:tid 140244498315008] [remote 79.53.204.195:37790]   File "/var/www/vhosts/Project/Project/wsgi.py", line 21, in <module>
[Sun Jan 23 14:08:08.310523 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 48106:tid 140244498315008] [remote 79.53.204.195:37790]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Sun Jan 23 14:08:08.310531 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 48106:tid 140244498315008] [remote 79.53.204.195:37790]   File "/var/www/vhosts/Project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Sun Jan 23 14:08:08.310534 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 48106:tid 140244498315008] [remote 79.53.204.195:37790]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Sun Jan 23 14:08:08.310540 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 48106:tid 140244498315008] [remote 79.53.204.195:37790]   File "/var/www/vhosts/Project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[Sun Jan 23 14:08:08.310543 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 48106:tid 140244498315008] [remote 79.53.204.195:37790]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Sun Jan 23 14:08:08.310549 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 48106:tid 140244498315008] [remote 79.53.204.195:37790]   File "/var/www/vhosts/Project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 83, in populate
[Sun Jan 23 14:08:08.310552 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 48106:tid 140244498315008] [remote 79.53.204.195:37790]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Sun Jan 23 14:08:08.310566 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 48106:tid 140244498315008] [remote 79.53.204.195:37790] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

Comment: Go to /var/log/apache2/error.log and say to us what error ,message you receive there

Comment: Did you tried the configuration that i give you?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    # This path must be the to the root of the project
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/Project

    # Static folder must be in the root of the project
    Alias /static/ /var/www/vhosts/Project/static

    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/Project/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/vhosts/Project/Project>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess Project python-home=/var/www/vhosts/Project/env python-path=/var/www/vhosts/Project 
    WSGIProcessGroup Project
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/Project/Project/wsgi.py
```

Comment: I have tried it but I still receive Error 500